# La cadena JSON no llega completa

Tags: json

Tengo un problema que ha surgido hace un par de días y no consigo entenderlo. A ver si consigo explicarlo bien: tengo que reproducir un listado de productos. En JavaScript lanzo un XMLHttpRequest contra un script en php y, hasta hace nada, todo salía bien: me devolvía la cadena y a partir de ahí mostraba los resultados.

Pero ahora resulta que en el archivo php sí están todos los resultados pero en en la cadena JSON que recibo en JavaScript, no, está incompleta.

[image: Final de la cadena en el archivo php]

Esto de aquí arriba es el final de la cadena en php. Y lo de aquí abajo, el final del alert que muestra la cadena que ha recibido:

[image: Final de la cadena que recibo]

Como veis, en el primero la cadena finaliza bien, con su llave y su corchete; en cambio, en JavaScript está incompleta con ese **"idHote** final. ¿Se le ocurre a alguien por qué puede ocurrir eso?

Debo señalar que soy un aficionadillo. Y muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Has intentado imprimir la cadena en **consola** y no en un **alert**?, te comento esto ya que al ser una cadena demasiado larga el _alert_ se llena y solo muestra hasta el tope de su limite, por ende se ve recortada la información.

Comment: Sí, tenías razón!! Muchísimas gracias :-)

Comment: Oye, ya de paso, jeje, ¿sabes cómo determinar que la pregunta ya está resuelta?

Comment: Solo si agrego mi comentario como respuesta y la puntúas con la flecha hacia arriba :), creo es la única forma.

Answer (score 1):

Has intentado imprimir la cadena en consola y no en un alert?, te comento esto ya que al ser una cadena demasiado larga el Alert se llena y solo muestra hasta el tope de su limite, por ende se ve recortada la información.

Ejemplo:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]]));
```